# Why is aluminium oxide solution amphoteric?

Tags: ph, electronegativity

Is Aluminium oxide solution amphoteric due to aluminium's electronegativity being in between 1.5 and 2.1.
If so why?

I believe it is because a AL-O-H molecule is made and it can either disassociate into a aluminium cation and a hydroxide, or a aluminium oxide anion and a proton. In this case the Al-O-H disassociates into both giving amphoteric properties, but how does electronegativity affect this?

Comment: Why is Al2O3 amphoteric? - because it can react as 'both' acid & base as amphoterism depends on the oxidation states of the oxide. (Housecroft, C. E.; Sharpe, A. G. (2004). Inorganic Chemistry (2nd ed.). Prentice Hall. pp. 173–4. ISBN 978-0-13-039913-7)

Amphoterism related - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphoterism#:~:text=Metal%20oxides%20which%20react%20with,example%20of%20an%20amphoteric%20oxide.

Comment: Electronegativity is a relative term so I would not comment on if 'that' is the reason for amphoterism.